# Text centered overlayed on video in Joomla module in HTML

Tags: css, html, video, joomla

Ok. Ive been struggling with this for a day. Can any one help?

I am trying to auto play a .mp4 video as the background in a Joomla CMS module with text overlaying on the top in the center of the module.

I decided simple html would be better than trying to find a plugin to do it.

Basically I want the video to auto play in the center (both horizontally and vertically) of the module. This is fairly easy as the video is the EXACT width of the module and height adjusts automatically. The module is responsive so no problems there. This code works:

```
<video width="1600" autoplay loop>
<source src="/newimages/capsulas-compatibles.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

What I struggle with, is putting and H1 title over the top of the video in the center (both horizontally and vertically). So I tried the following html but the text simply appear before the video, not overlayed in the center of the video:

```
<div style="z-index:10; position:relative; top:0; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; ">
<h1><font color="white">HERE IS MY TEXT</font></h1></div>
<div style="z-index:1;"><video width="1600" autoplay loop>
<source src="/newimages/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
```

Is it a problem with my code or that it is in a Joomla module?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to give h1 div position to absolute and set left and top to 50%

Comment: That's it! Thank you for taking the time to answer. You really have made someones day (mine!)

Comment: You welcome. I post it as a answer so. it may help to some one else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following it will solve your issue:

```
<div style="z-index:10; position:relative; top:50%; left:50%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; position:absolute; ">
<h1><font color="white">HERE IS MY TEXT</font></h1></div>
<div style="z-index:1;"><video width="1600" autoplay loop>
<source src="/newimages/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
```

Make H1 DIV `position:absolute;` and give `left:50%;` and `top:50%;`.