# Set a div width without padding/margin

Tags: html, css

I would like to set my title block like the following picture :

[image]

Actually i have that :

[image]

The title block width need to be equal to the width of the picture without the margin/padding in green. 
How can i set my block ?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7cLtz49/

Comment: Yes why don't you set that image as background image of container div..?

Comment: It's not a solution, i want to do that with a balise image

Comment: than  you can use position:absolute style for the title and set it with top: 10px;

Comment: i tried the position:absolute :/

Comment: can you share a link of fiddle?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739231/text-centered-overlayed-on-video-in-joomla-module-in-html/28739833#28739833

Comment: @Ricoxor the problem is with markup
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
class name define over here are taking width from bootstrap.css
So, you need to change the markup and use your own css instead of bootstrap one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7cLtz49/

Comment: @Ricoxor you can find the answer below and a link here: http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/zxadGB

Comment: @VilasKumkar Can you make an answer ? Your solution work !

Comment: @Ricoxor the answer is already here, you can checkout down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout this one
http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/zxadGB

```
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="imgHolder">
                        <div class="test"></div>
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I guess this might help you, I've updated your markup

Answer (score 0):

You should put your container on position relative and your title on absolute with background alpha like:

```css
.post {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

Comment: You dont following my code on your fiddle, so obviously it doesn't work

Comment: What padding? Where? Just follow the solution, put a class of your container set on relative and put your title on absolute, click on run code snippet

Comment: See my fiddle. There is padding with the responsives class ="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
.title {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 90px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and html is

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```